# Special formal lifts of smooth algebras

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let $A$ be a smooth algebra over $k$ a finite field.

Say $B$ is a $p$-adically complete smooth algebra over the Witt ring $W(k)$, lifting $A$.

Assume $B$ is of the form $W(k)\langle t_1,\ldots, t_n\rangle / (f_1,\ldots, f_m)$.

> Can the $f_j$'s be arranged so that their coefficients are all $p$-adic units, without affecting smoothness of $B$?

Here is what I would like to stay invariant:

- the mod $p$ fiber
- smoothness of the $B$ obtained by modifying the $f_j$'s

I guess I can equivalently ask if, for any smooth $k$-algebra $A$, one can find a $B$ of the form up there, with all $f_j$'s with $p$-adic units as coefficients

Comment: It is impossible to answer without clarification of you are asking for. Do you actually mean "without affecting $B$"? Do you want to keep $n$ and $m$ to be the same?

Comment: @js21 Thanks. I added a clarification

Comment: A trivial observation which does not answer your question, but could be sufficient for some applications you may have in mind. (1) If $A$ is a complete intersection, i.e. $A=k[t_1, \ldots, t_n]/(f_1, \ldots, f_m)$ with ${\rm dim}(A) = n-m$, then any lifts of the $f_i$ define a smooth lifting $B$. So you can e.g. take Teichmuller lifts of the coefficients, and you're done. (2) Every smooth algebra $A/k$ is locally a complete intersection.